# Pointers and Reallocation in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

I'm fairly new to C; been at it for 3 weeks in a class. I am having a bit of trouble with pointers, and am sure there is probably an easy fix. So basically, this program is supposed to read a word from an input file, store it in an array of pointers with memory allocation, print the word and the normalized form of the word (irrelevant process), and then reallocate the space so that the pointer array will grow as more words are inputted. However, I am having a bit of trouble getting the words to print and the array to reallocate (I currently have it set to a fixed size just to troubleshoot the whole printing aspect). Let me know if there is something wrong with my variable declarations, or if I am just making a stupid mistake please (I am sure it is the probably a combination of the two). Again, I'm very new to C, so I apologize if this is an easy question.

```
char * word_regular[100];
char * word_norm[100];

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("You have not entered a valid number of files.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE * f_in = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int i = 0;
    char word[512];
    char norm_word[512];

    while(fscanf(f_in, "%s", word) != EOF) {
        if (is_valid_entry(word)) {
            word_regular[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(word) + 1);
            strcpy(word_regular[i],word);
            printf("%s\n",*word_regular[i]);
            word_norm[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(norm_word) + 1);
            normalize(word, norm_word);
            strcpy(word_norm[i],norm_word);
            printf("%s\n", *word_norm[i]);
            i++;
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n",*word_regular[i]);` --> `printf("%s\n", word_regular[i]);`, `printf("%s\n", *norm_word[i]);` ditto. also `norm_word` is not read. but use `strlen(norm_word)`

Comment: `word_norm[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(norm_word) + 1); normalize(word, norm_word);` : exchange position.

Comment: when i try to printf with just word_regular[i], i get the error "'%s\n' expects type char * but argument 2 has type int. Any idea how I might be able to fix this? word[] is of type char, so i would have assumed copying its address into word_regular would have made word_regular[i] also of type char.

Comment: type of `word_regular[i]` is `char*`. (because `char * word_regular[100];`)

Comment: that's what i thought. for some reason, however, it is giving me a type int error. When I go through it with gdb, it does not look like strcpy is functioning, so no address is being copied into the address that word_regular points to. Any possible solutions?

Comment: I can not talk because you seem to look at the code of another with me.

Comment: what do you mean? what you have been saying is what i have been doing the entire time. i get a warning every time that it is not of the right type to be displayed. When I run the program, it looks like I am getting a seg fault trying to print word_norm, because i believe word_norm is 512 characters even though the example word is only 4 ("This" to be specific). ill include the normalize function as well... maybe something wrong there?

Comment: _i believe word_norm is 512 characters_ you talk about `char norm_word[512];`, not `char * word_norm[100];`. This confusion of you has been pointed out already.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems that are with your current code (ignoring the dynamic size need as opposed to fixed since you already said you are using that to debug),

```
printf("%s\n",*word_regular[i]);
```

%s takes a char * for printing, so it should be

```
printf("%s\n",word_regular[i]);
```

For the second printf, since norm_word itself is a char array,

you should simply use

```
printf("%s\n", &norm_word[i]);
```

If you want to print string starting from the ith index.

**Update**:
A quick tip is to pay attention whether you are copying the \0 with strings or not. Because your api calls, such as strlen would go beyond string crashing (or worst silently), unless it is null terminated.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", &norm_word[i]);` --> `printf("%s\n", word_norm[i]);`

Comment: yeah i just wanted to fix the indirection instead of replacing with a different array name

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem with your `printf` call is that you pass a `char` (`*word_regular[i]`, `*norm_word[i]`) instead of `char *` (`word_regular[i]`, `word_norm[i]`) when trying to print a string.
2. If you want to dynamically grow the array, you need to dynamically allocate it in the first place, so instead of declaring arrays of pointers:

   ```
   char * word_regular[100];
   char * word_norm[100];
   ```

   You need to declare pointers to pointers:

   ```
   char ** word_regular;
   char ** word_norm;
   ```

   Allocate an initial buffer for them (in a function, main for example):

   ```
   word_regular = malloc(sizeof(char *) * INITIAL_AMOUNT);
   ```

   Then reallocate them as needed.

   ```
   word_regular = realloc(word_regular, sizeof(char *) * new_amount);
   ```

   You will need to keep track of the amount of pointers in the arrays, and free them properly of course...

Comment: Or initialize with `char ** word_norm = NULL` and only use `realloc()` as in `word_regular = realloc(word_regular, new_amount);`

Comment: Agree about initialization, I think `realloc`ing in the first time is a matter of style. When explaining I prefer doing it separately for clarity (at least in my head :) )

Comment: Either way works for me, but your `realloc(sizeof(char *) * new_amount) ` gets 1 parameter.  It should get 2.